# How can I attack resonators in the middle of a city block?

Tags: ingress

I was trying to attack a portal today, but I couldn't destroy the last few resonators because on the map they exist in the middle of a city block.  I tried going in the building, but the gps signal is gone at that point and it didn't get me any closer to those resonators.

How do I destroy resonators I can't get close to?  Do I just need to launch a ton of xmps from a distance and do around 1% - 2% damage at a time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If it is only a couple of resonators, it is actually ok, landmarks are very often the walls of big buildings like churches, so there is always a chance a couple of resonators will land inside it and will be only partially accessible.

You can always blow it up with high level xmp, unfortunately high level players are well aware of this exploit and try to place their strongest resonators at the blocked side of a portal.

If you on the other hand cannot access a portal itself, report it to ingress and suggest coordinate adjustment. https://support.google.com/ingress

Comment: High level xmp busters aren't much help when you're a low level player.  I would advise low level players to avoid attacking portals where some of the resonators are hard to get to - it's frustrating.  Level 1 xmp busters do almost nothing unless you're right on top of the resonator.

Comment: This is true, even for l6 players it could be a pickle to blow up a  L6 resonator you can only get 40 meter close to.

Answer (score 7):

Yes , get as close as you can. If you want to get tricky turn off your wifi, you will now determine your position solely by satelites, this can vary depending on if it's raining, if you're under a tree, or if you're next to a wall.

E.G. you might want to go into a city block, but be up against the wall not able to get to that resonator; try crossing the street and get up against the other wall, you might accidentally mirror off the wall a little, ending up closer than you could get before.

Comment: I like the idea of turning off wifi as a trick, but I tried that today and it said my location wasn't accurate enough and wouldn't let me do anything until I turned it back on.  I think my problem is that I'm not getting gps signal, so it's relying entirely on wifi for really inaccurate location data.

Answer (score 5):

For now, yes. But you have the option of reporting the portal as not being publicly accessible on the website.

Comment: The link to report portal issues and a lot of other things for the game is https://support.google.com/ingress.  Then there's a "Contact Us" button.

Answer (score 1):

This happens way too frequently for Google to adjust coordinates for every instance of this. You are going to have to accept that tactical placement of resonators can make it difficult to attack. The problem swings both ways. There is no reason for google to address it.

Take note of the placement, because when you do get it down you are going to want to place it in the exact same place!

Try moving to windows within the building. You may not be able to get right on top of it but you may get closer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to stand exactly on the top of a resonator. You may stand 8-10 meters from the resonator for L1-L3 xmps and still hit it with full effect.

The xmp effect is decreased in steps of the distance. For a full detailed explanation see the Google+ group here:[Decode Ingress (Help/Game)](https://plus.google.com/u/0/102799262315059204113/posts/d5P6Sicrhto)

Answer (score -2):

Ask a high-level player to nuke it. High-level XMP bursters have a huge radius.

Comment: That doesn't really help whoever's playing to do it.